# Empty columns at end of line in csv export are removed

Tags: laravel, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I use laravel-excel to create a csv export from a Laravel collection. This collection can include empty columns at the end of a row. The dataset pushed to the store() function does include these empty values. However, while exporting, it seems that those empty columns are removed. The dataset doesn't include a header line, because I don't need that to be in the export.

For example: I would expect the output of one line to be `test;1;2;;;;test;;;;`

But instead I get: `test;1;2;;;;test`

I use this code to produce the csv file:

```
Excel::store($export, $fileName . $extension, 'public');
```

where `$export` is the element containing the collection.

Is it possible to force laravel-excel to include these empty values at the end of the file? I need this because the import tool I use later on in the process counts the columns, and now fails because the amount of columns isn't correct.

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!